# Cant compile and running python in slax

Tags: python, linux, terminal

I want to execute Python programs with terminal but it says `command not found`.

I am using Linux Slax version 7.0.1 and tried running `python script.py` but it is not running.

Comment: You should install Python first. Go to Python's official site and read the docs about the installation process.

Comment: Or install a Linux distro that has Python already

Comment: @ForceBru I can't connect to the internet, an alternatives solution to do this

Answer (score 1):

Install [python](https://www.slax.org/en/modules.php?detail=python&category=develop) or [python3](https://www.slax.org/en/modules.php?detail=python3&category=develop) from slax packages.

Comment: But I can't connect to the internet, an alternatives solution to do this

Comment: [Download](https://www.slax.org/en/download.php) SLAX CD or USB and use it locally.

Comment: you sure the package want do it or Im download the new python and installing the package for example up vote, right thanks for help us